# Updating ViewState using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, postback, viewstate

I started to use jQuery more intensively and especially .ajax() in jQuery.  I would like to know if it is a good idea to manipulate ViewState using .ajax() or if there is a better way to manipulate ViewState without a full postback.

Comment: Why would you need to alter the ViewState client-side? Just curious...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very specific reason and know what you are doing, this sounds like an approach that will lead you into a lot of pain. ViewState isn't meant to be modified by the client.

Why would you want to do this? I would guess that there is an easier and more maintainable way of achieving what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. Apart from the fact that you will be having to deal with an encoded string, any error would result in a full page post back failing.

If you need to pass data that was the result of ajax queries back to the server during a postback I would suggest storing it in a hidden field or fields and retrieving them from the form collection on the server.